# How to break GCM that uses the same IV

Tags: security, encryption, openssl

I have an implementation done with `OpenSSL`'s `EVP` library that natively uses the same IV (12 bytes of `0`) for all encryption. The key is always a 32 byte SHA512 hash. I know via this [post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/57645/is-using-the-same-iv-in-aes-similar-to-not-using-an-iv-in-the-first-place) that I can

> 1) deduce the bit-wise xor of the two plaintexts.
>
> 2) deduce the internal authentication value, and thus modify the ciphertexts without being detected.

But how can I actually achieve either of these?

Comment: You need to study the encryption and authentication equations. That should tell you everything. If not, ask your question on crypto.